# Providing proof to Agda functions

Tags: agda

Given the following fragments (taken from the tutorial by Ulf Norell
and James Chapman), I understand the caller of **lookup** must provide a proof that the index **ix** of the required item is valid but I just can't find the right form to do it.

```
data Proven-n : Set where
record Proven-y : Set where

-- using the name 'isProven' instead of 'isTrue' of the tutorial
isProven : Bool -> Set 
isProven true = Proven-y
isProven false = Proven-n

lookup : {A : Set}(xs : List A)(ix : Nat) -> isProven (n < length xs) -> A
```

I've managed to work out the special case below, but all my attempts for a more general application of **lookup**, where the vector and the lookup index are produced in another function, have failed. I'd like to understand the concept of passing around proofs. Please help.

```
aList : List Bool
aList = true :: false :: []

aTest: Bool 
aTest = lookup aList 0 (record {})
```

Comment: Could you provide an example application of `lookup` which doesn't work out for you, including any relevant definitions (like `_<_`)? It's unclear to me where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: For instance, I'd like aTest to receive ix as a parameter: aTest (ix : Nat) -> Bool. How do I forward a proof of ix being valid to lookup then: lookup aList ix <???>. (_<_) is the normal less-than operator for Nat.

Comment: Are you sure you want `aTest : Nat -> Bool`? That would mean `aTest` yields a value of `Bool` for *any* `Nat`. I'm guessing you want something like `aTest : Nat -> Maybe Bool`, returning `nothing` in case the given index is out-of-bounds.

Comment: You could and should have provided a fully-typechecked Agda program in the OP because, as it stands, it makes the answerers' jobs tougher. You're missing the required imports and a definition of `lookup`. (It also would have been appropriate to declare lookup as a `postulate`.) And `lookup` and `aTest` contain (obvious?) typos. My suggested (but rejected) edit to the OP is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16903552).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The below makes more sense as a response to the question as edited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16903552).

I'm guessing you want something like `aTest : Nat -> Maybe Bool`, returning `nothing` in case the given index is out-of-bounds. In that case, the following will do:

```
data Decide (P : Set) : Set where
  yes : P -> Decide P
  no : (P -> Proven-n) -> Decide P

okay? : ∀ {A : Set} (xs : List A) (ix : Nat) -> Decide (isProven (ix < length xs))
okay? [] ix = no λ ()
okay? (_ ∷ xs) zero = yes record {}
okay? (_ ∷ xs) (suc ix) = okay? xs ix

data Maybe (A : Set) : Set where
  nothing : Maybe A
  just : A -> Maybe A

aTest : Nat -> Maybe Bool
aTest ix with okay? aList ix
... | yes ix<len = just (lookup aList ix ix<len)
... | no ix≥len = nothing
```

In the above, `aTest` uses `okay?` to decide whether the index is within bounds. If it is, the proof (carried by `Decide`) is passed to `lookup`.

Comment: It looks like the way I did it, the same (or very similar) proof is done twice, once for `okay?` and again for `lookup`. I'm not sure if that affects performance, or, if it does, exactly the best way to fix it. But that's a different question.